# how we can make a word refer to something like a section or a picture in latex?

Tags: latex, href, ref, xelatex, hyperref

how we can make a word refer to something like a section or a picture in latex?
I know how to refer to something by \ref{} but when we use this we see the number of the section or table or picture or ... but I wanna something like \href{}{} to make a word refer to some element like section, table, picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `\hyperlink`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\section{title}
\label{test}

\newpage


\hyperlink{test}{link text}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
\hyperref[test]{link text}
```

which worked for me when `\hyperlink` did not. Note the square brackets.